# PowerShell for applying Entity Framework migrations?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, powershell, migration

I'm using a PowerShell to apply EF migrations. It's working, the only problem is it's still successful if there are any error while applying the migration. I want to be able to throw an exception if there are any errors while applying migrations. Couldn't find anything on how to do that. Here is my script:

```
  try
 {
#all relative paths are relative to where xyzabc.sln is

#copy migrate.exe to xyzabcWebRole\bin
Copy-Item packages\EntityFramework*\tools\migrate.exe xyzabc\path\xyzabcWebRole\bin -ErrorAction "Stop"

#migrate 
$migrator = "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f791999b69d7a83e\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\migrate.exe" 
$migrateCommand = "$migrator xyzabcWebRole.dll /StartUpDirectory=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f791999b69d7a83e\xyzabcWebRole\bin /connectionStringName:MyDBConnectionString /startUpConfigurationFile:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f791999b69d7a83e\xyzabc\path\xyzabcWebRole\Web.config /verbose"  

Write-Host $migrateCommand
Invoke-Expression $migrateCommand


}
  catch [System.Exception]
{
Write-Host $_.Exception.ToString()
exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable after you invoke the migration and throw an exception